# How to Pass Image File and Some Data From Ajax to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view to display image upload button and a list of photos as follows:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" multiple />
<input type="submit" id="Upload" value="Upload" />

<table class="table">

<!-- A table goes here to view the images from a table in the database using @foreach as below where Model is a list of images obtained from the database: -->

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cover)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Image("/Images/" + item.id_product + "/" + item.id_product + ".jpg", "Image", "50")
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.type)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Upload").click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
            {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Products/Upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('succes!!');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("errror");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

My controller action that is supposed to receive the uploaded file is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Upload()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
                if(this.CreateFolderIfNeeded(path))
                    file.SaveAs(path + fileName);
            }
        }
```

And in the main view I have the following:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("All", "All", "Products", new { id = Model.id_product }, new AjaxOptions()
       {
           HttpMethod = "GET",
           UpdateTargetId = "divImages",
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
       })
                <div id="divImages"></div>
```

And the `all(int id)` method above is used to return a partial view with a list of images from the database.

Now, I have the following requirement:

After the user click on the upload button, I want to pass a parameter (`@Model.Take(1).Single().id_product`) to the `ActionMethod` `Upload()` in the controller to save the path (which is named according to `@Model.Take(1).Single().id_product`) of the uploaded image in the database.

Also I want after the image is uploaded successfully, I want to refresh the partial view (table) automatically to view the newly uploaded image.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: If you wrap your file input and submit button in a `<form>` tag, then you can use just `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` then you can add an additional value using `formdata,append(id: 'yourValue');` And change the method to `public void Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int ID)` (and give the file input a `name attribute - `name="files"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke has it been explained somewhere?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for additional information

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanx alot, very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Stephen Muecke's comment above. It services as answer to my question. I copied and pasted here so that people can see it:

If you wrap your file input and submit button in a `<form>` tag, then you can use just

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
```

then you can add an additional value using `formdata,append(id: 'yourValue');` And change the method to

```
public void Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, int ID)
```

and give the file input a `name` attribute - `name="files"`

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293681/1016716) for additional information.